# Why do we need to use fake k-points when doing HSE band structure in VASP?

Tags: vasp, band-structure, symmetry, k-points, hse06

I want to know why we need fake k-points in HSE band structure calculation? I mean why we can't take a simple high symmetric path like we do in PBE calculation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!!

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that the HSE method are obtaining the band structure with self-consistent calculation rather than non-self-consistent calculation like PBE band structure calculation. For self-consistent calculation, you will sample the k-space with a uniform k mesh. The fake k-points are just the high-symmetry path used in PBE calculations, which are added into the self-consistent calculations to calculate the eigenvalues or energy band you are wanted.

Comment: ok so what if I do the HSE  calculation in the same manner as we do PBE calculation? Is there any specific advantage or motive to do the HSE calculation in a different manner i.e. the fake k-point procedure.

Comment: You can try and see what will happen.

Answer (score 6):

This question has already been answered in the quantum espresso forum [here](https://lists.quantum-espresso.org/pipermail/users/2018-April/040575.html). To reiterate the Fock operator at a certain k-point needs the wavefunction on a grid that is commensurate with it. Hence we cannot calculate the single k-point non-selfconsistently from the charge density. Therefore, in a hybrid functional we have to  use the entire self consistent calculations.

Comment: Ok I understood what you are trying to say but what if I do a first self consistent calculation(SCF) with HSE tags and I take the WAVECAR of this SCF as you mentioned Fock operator needs the wavefunction on the grid and now with this WAVECAR I do non-SCF calculation with high symmetry K-point path. I know I am adding an extra step but I just want to know will it give the same results?